# Какие существуют подходы при организации загружаемых пользователями файлов с использованием Docker, но без сторонних сервисов (таких как AWS Bucket)?

Tags: docker, vps, хранение-данных

Подождите писать в комментариях ссылки на **bind mounting** и **volume** - эта задача гораздо более многомерная, чем выбор способа хранения данных в Docker. Тут необходимо и на уровне организации Docker-образов поразмыслить, да и при покупке VPS задуматься о дополнительных опциях.

Заранее прошу прощение за длинный вопрос. Длинный он потому, что мне нужно было показать ход моих мыслей, а также что я знаю и чего ещё не знаю.

Что мы имеем изначально? Обычно в проекте серверного приложения у нас есть какая-то папка для хранения загружаемых пользователями файлов. На примере Laravel, это `storage/app/public`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иногда полученные от пользователей файлы сохраняют и в **public** (причём не только в случае PHP и Laravel), но я не уверен, что это хорошая идея - смешивать в одну кучу файлы, подготовленные разработчиками (стили, логотипы, иконки и так далее) и загруженные пользователями.

В отличие от таких языков, как PHP, в моём случае (TypeScript + Node.js) выходной код *полностью* отделён от исходного, и та структура файлов, что на картинке ниже, на 100% сгенерирована (даже `package.json` - это не тот, что в корне проекта; из этого сгенерированного `package.json` *полностью* исключены зависимости для разработки и те, что подшиты Webpack-ом к скриптам для фронтенда):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент у меня 2 volum-а: один для базы данных и другой - для файлов проекта, который создаётся автоматически командой `COPY . /var/www/example.com`, прописанной в **FrontServer.Dockerfile**. Я не говорю, что именно так и делаю, но в теории до тех пор, пока не принималось никаких файлов от пользователей, во время деплоя можно было *безопасно* удалить volume *проекта* (потому что данные базы данных хранятся на другом volum-е) и добавленные ранее файлы на картинке выше, и только потом загрузить на сервер файлы собранного проекта заново, установить свежие зависимости и запустить приложение. В реальности я это делаю с помощью **rsync**, причём с опцией `—delete`, удаляющей файлы, которых нет в источники. Теперь же планируется начать принимать файлы от пользователей, а потому необходимо внести изменения в процесс деплоя.

Как я уже сказал выше, не думаю, что это хорошая идея - хранить их **public**. При таком раскладе, как сейчас, добавленные пользователями файлы будут просто потеряны, и хотя их можно хранить в одной из подпапок по отношению к **public**, исключённой из отслеживания **rsync**, ошибка может привести к потере данных. Какие ещё варианты мне известны?

### Вариант 1: Хранить загружаемые пользователями файлы в отдельной папке + на отдельном volume

Аналогично Laravel, помимо `public` добавить папку `storage` для файлов, принимаемых от пользователей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный вариант не предполагает добавления новых образов и контейнеров, а вот насчёт Volum-ов надо подумать. Начнём с того, сама папка `06-ProductionBuilding` уже соответствует Volume-у, а тут в ней ещё и `storage` появится, которой должен соответствовать отдельному Volum-у. На данный момент точно не знаю, но не уверен, что так можно.

Затем, возможно для данного случая и **bind mounting** ничем не хуже.
Однако какой бы вариант не был выбран, при деплое новой версии проекта нужно быть осторожным, чтобы не тронуть папку **storage**, а такой расклад - хорошая почва для гипотетического инцидента потери данных пользователей.

### Вариант 2: Создать отдельный образ

Возможно, работу с изображениями и другими мультимедийными файлами следует вообще переложить на отдельные образ и контейнер, а не только volume. Сейчас у меня 2 образа: node.js (front_server) и PostgreSQL:

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  front_server:

    container_name: Example-Production-FrontServer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "FrontServer.Dockerfile"
    ports: [ "8080:8080" ]

    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=Database

    depends_on: [ Database ]

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Example-Production-Database
    ports: [ "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}" ]

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/data/example.com

volumes:
  DatabaseData: {}
```

но говорят, что для отдачи файлов лучше организовать отдельных сервер, например Nginx. Так как в случае с Docker это не означает покупку ещё одного сервера, то почему бы и нет: отдельный образ, отдельный контейнер, отдельный volume, лёгкость в резервировании данных. Я даже думаю, что при таком раскладе можно у поставщика VPS и отдельный диск арендовать для хранения на нём только файлов, загруженных пользователями.

### Требования конкретно для моей задачи

Если кратко, то начальные требования весьма скромные, на уровне сайта с фотографиями для относительно узкого круга людей, однако ввиду того, что будет вестись блог с загрузкой новых фотографий, нужно чтобы при необходимости было легко расширить начальный объём доступной памяти.

- **Требования к размеру хранилища файлов**: Для начала хватит 2-3Гб, но надо, чтобы этот объём было легко увеличить при необходимости
- **Отказоусточивость**: На данный момент создавать несколько реплик, чтобы при отказе одного сервера файлы были доступны, не требуется ввиду малого масштаба проекта. Сейчас достаточно иметь возможность извлечь файлы в процессе процедуры восстановления данных без сверхусилий, если что-то случится.
- **Планируется ли использовать хранилище другими сайтами / приложениями**: нет
- **Быстродействие**: точного приемлемого интервала времени загрузки изображений не назову, но достаточно среднестатистической скорости загрузки картиной - пускай и не мгновенно, но и не как во времена модема. Адаптация сайта для зарубежных посетителей не планируется. Б*о*льшая часть файлов - изображения; хранить огромные файлы по несколько гигабайт не планируется.
- **Пропуская способность**: особых требований нет; расчётный траффик очень далёк до уровня социальных сетей.

### Итог

Наверное, есть и друге варианты, но мне известны только эти два.
Напомню, что в данном вопросе мы не рассматриваем варианты сторонних сервисов, аналогичных AWS Bucket - сейчас задача понять, чего можно достичь с помощью одного VPS и Docker-а.

Comment: Я совсем не спец и потому пишу комментарием, но по моему ваш вопрос сильно общий. Вы можете в базу ложить файлы или в папку или поднять аналог s3 хранилища, но плюсы и минусы этих вариантов надо глядеть в контексте вашей задачи и того, как вы будете дальше обновлять / развивать ваше приложение.

Comment: @tym32167 Хорошо, я готов уточнить свою задачу, для чего уже опубликовал и структуру собранного приложения, и Dockerfile. Требования - отсутствие перемешивания открытых файлов от разработчиков и от пользователей, лёгкость в резервивании данных и максимально быстрая для отсутствия CDN скорость загрузки изображений. Что ещё мне следует добавить?

Comment: Ну, например, у вас есть требования а размеру хранилища файлов? К отказоустойчивости? Это хранилище только для обслуживания вашего сайта? Единственного сервера? А есть требования к быстродействию?  Есть требования к пропускной способности канала хранилища? Ну и все в таком духе. Если вам подходит обычная папка на той же виртуалке как решение - то я бы не заморачивался. Если вам надо отказоустойчивое, масштабируемое решение - ну тут папкой не обойтись

Comment: @tym32167 Добавил указанную Вами информацию в вопрос.

Comment: Исходя из инфы, что вы добавили, я бы сделал папочку на хосте, добавил ее как volume, и в ней хранил бы конфигурацию, логи и картинки сразу, чтобы обновление докер контейнера не задевало эти данные. Но еще раз, я не спец, чисто говорю куда бы я думал.

Comment: @tym32167 Ну что же, тогда самое время начать конкурс!